# Could I change ubuntu kernel as a customized one?

Tags: boot, kernel, compiling

If I want to change my kernel as customized one, below sequence is ok?

1. download kernel source from kernel.org.
2. do something with it.
3. build it.
4. copy vmlinux,.etc into /boot folder.
5. reboot and choose custom kernel with grub, during boot.

I'm curious that this procedure is safe if I want to change my ubuntu 18.04 kernel (5.4) into 4.14 or older one. (3.18 or older)

Thank you.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, this is how it works. But it will take a lot of time, both to configure the kernel and most likely also recovering from failed boots. You will save a lot of time if you start from a working Ubuntu kernel source package. See e.g. the tips in https://askubuntu.com/a/30475/134479 and elsewhere on the web.

Comment: For your step 4, I would install the .deb files, and would have specified to make them for step 3. It makes kernel management easier and will also update grub. You might have difficulties trying to go to such old kernels. Also see my notes [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662).

Comment: Sorry for late response. Many thanks to all !!